# DomXPath->query do not get HTML tags

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I'm getting the content from a DOMDocument and using query to get a certain part of the DOM.

I get the content perfectly but not the HTML tags, only pure text.

Here is the code I use:

```
$DOM                     = file_get_contents($link);
    $doc                     = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTML($DOM);
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);

    $founds     = 0;
    $nodes      = $finder->query("//div[contains(@class, 'td-post-content td-pb-padding-side')]");
    foreach ( $nodes as $entrada ) {
        if ( $founds == 0 ) {
                $description = $entrada->nodeValue;
        } $founds++;
    }
```

Once I echo $description, no html tags like `<p> <div>` and so on, are not included.

What's wrong?

Comment: `echo $doc->saveHTML($entrada);`

Comment: Yes!!!  It works!  Thanks.